# WPF TabControl - Changing SelectedItem during an ItemsSource-CollectionChanged event

Tags: c#, wpf

I have experienced some odd behavior with the WPF TabControl. With other Selector based classes like the ComboBox I could not reproduce it.

When I have a TabControl bound to an ItemsSource and I add an item to it, so that the CollectionChanged-event is fired, I try to change the SelectedItem property in the event handler. Unfortunately the UI doesn't update itself. The Content changes but the Header is not selected.

My XAML:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ints}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedInt}"/>
```

My code:

```
  public class ViewModel
    {
            private int selectedInt;

            public ObservableCollection<int> Ints { get; set; }

            public int SelectedInt
            {
                get { return this.selectedInt; }
                set
                {
                    this.selectedInt = value;
                    this.NotifyOfPropertyChange();
                }
            }

            public ViewModel(){
                 this.ints.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) => this.SelectedInt = this.ints.First();
                 // We have to call the Add-method asynchronously before adding an item to ensure the TabControl is loaded.
                 Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => this.ints.Add(2);}));
             }
    }
```

When I don't have an event handler for the CollectionChanged event, but I directly set the SelectedItem property after adding an item, then everything works fine:

```
this.ints.Add(2);
this.SelectedInt = this.ints.First();
```

Also changing the SelectedItem property asynchronously causes the UI to update itself correctly:

```
this.ints.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) => Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => this.SelectedInt = this.ints.First()));
```

It seems that the PropertyChanged event of the SelectedItem property is not propagated correctly when it is invoked during an CollectionChanged-event. It may be absorbed in some way.

What is the exact explanation for this behavior?

Comment: Did you try setting the SelectedItem's Binding Mode to `Two Way` ?